# Bibliography as \section instead of \section*

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I’m writing on my thesis at the moment and have a problem with the bibliography. I want to have a bibliography for every chapter. I included the `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` command. The bibliography is now in the list of contents, but not as section. How can I change the `sectionbib` to make a `\section` of it instead of a `\section*`?

Comment: According to page 3 of the documentation of the `chapterbib` package, its option `sectionbib` is equivalent to `\sectionbib{\section*}{section}` being put into the preamble. So `\usepackage{chapterbib}\sectionbib{\section}{section}` (with the asterisk removed) should do what you (seem to) want.

Comment: @Crissov -- The package's "sectionbib" option causes a *delayed execution* of the instruction `\sectionbib{\section*}{section}`. It's therefore necessary to issue the instruction `\sectionbib{\section}{section}` *after* the `\begin{document}` instruction.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can accept the answer that helped you most. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). You can also upvote both answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is another solution, with the package `tocbibind`.

Load `chapterbib` as

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
```

and `tocbibind` as

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

The option `nottoc` avoids the ToC to be inserted in the ToC itself, while the option `numbib` transforms the bibliography in a non-starred `\section`.

MWE (kindly borrowed from Harish' one):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{book-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{Second Chapter}
  \section{Another section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{article-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
%% this too becomes a section not \chapter*
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From `chapterbib` documentation

> The report and book document classes usually treat the bibliography as
>   an unnumbered chapter (\chapter*), which is not so good for
>   bibliographies in a chapter. You can specify
>   \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} to convert your bibliographies
>   from \chapter* to \section*, with an entry in the table of contents
>   and the page-header. A bibliog- raphy in the root file remains as a
>   \chapter*. The [sectionbib] option modifies the existing
>   thebibliography environment (or the \bibsection command, if present
>   already), so the other formatting in the bibliography should remain
>   unchanged. On the other hand, if you already have a non-standard
>   bibliography defined, or if you want them numbered, it may be easier
>   to redefine \thebibliography directly, without any tricky modification
>   of existing commands.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the \sectionbib
>   command directly in the document preamble. It takes two parameters:
>   the sectioning command, and the name of the sectioning level. For
>   instance, the [sectionbib] option executes
>   \sectionbib{\section*}{section}. Again, for the most control, it is
>   better to redefine \thebibliography entirely.

We follow the manual and patch `thebibliography` ourselves using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{book-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{Second Chapter}
  \section{Another section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{article-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
%% this too becomes a section not \chapter*
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Caveat**

I have already included a sample in the code with a comment. If you want a collective bibliography in the root file at the end, it also gets formatted as a section (not as a `\chapter*`). Hope you won't need it.