# Bibliography as \section and included in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

Previous questions ([chapterbib as section not chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280511) et al.) have considered how to include bibliographies at the end chapters. This question concerns bibliographies at the end of chapters when natbib is used as a citation package.

In the preamble, I wrote

```
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

in each `\include`(d) file.  I ran `LaTeX` on the main file (`test2.tex`) and `bibtex` on each auxillary file (`chap1.aux` and `chap2.aux`), and then `LaTeX` again, twice, on `test2.tex`. This gave:

- The correct style (from `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`)
- The references inserted as a numbered section (from `\usepackage{chapterbib)` and using `\patchcmd`)
- BUT, the section that includes the references is excluded from the Table of Contents

What is the correct way to use `natbib` to have references placed as a section within a chapter and included in the Table of Contents? If `\usepackage{natbib}` is excluded, the code generates references that are included as a numbered section as well as being included in the Table of Contents, but (of course) the `natbib` style is not applied.

I have read the `chapterbib` (Arseneau 2010) and `natbib` (Daly 2010) reference material entirely.

Here is my minimum non-working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%patchcmd from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158871/bibliography-as-section-instead-of-section
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First chapter, first section}
Watson and Crick \citeyearpar{watson53} proposed the structure of DNA.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second chapter, first section}
This is Einstein's famous paper \citep{einstein05}.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{
watson53,
Author = {Watson, J. D. and Crick, F. H. C.},
Title = {Molecular Structure of Nucleic Acids: A Structure for Deoxyribose Nucleic Acid},
Journal = {Nature},
Volume = {171},
Number = {4356},
Pages = {737-738},
Year = {1953} }
@article
{einstein05,
Title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}.        ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
Author  = {Albert Einstein},
Journal = {Annalen der Physik},
Year    = {1905},
Number  = {10},
Pages   = {891--921},
Volume  = {322}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: check out `addcontentsline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using solution given here: [How can I add the bibliography in a report with its own section, including number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/how-can-i-add-the-bibliography-in-a-report-with-its-own-section-including-numbe).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%Don't use this
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158871/bibliography-as-section-instead-of-section
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{} 
%Use the following patch and \renewcommand inside \begin{document}
%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/how-can-i-add-the-bibliography-in-a-report-with-its-own-section-including-numbe
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
\chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}    {\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{%
\section{References}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First chapter, first section}
Watson and Crick \citeyearpar{watson53} proposed the structure of DNA.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second chapter, first section}
This is Einstein's famous paper \citep{einstein05}.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{
watson53,
Author = {Watson, J. D. and Crick, F. H. C.},
Title = {Molecular Structure of Nucleic Acids: A Structure for Deoxyribose Nucleic Acid},
Journal = {Nature},
Volume = {171},
Number = {4356},
Pages = {737-738},
Year = {1953} }
@article
{einstein05,
Title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}.        ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
Author  = {Albert Einstein},
Journal = {Annalen der Physik},
Year    = {1905},
Number  = {10},
Pages   = {891--921},
Volume  = {322}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```