# Making Bibliography as a Subsection in TOC, but chapter in document

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning, formatting

I have seen a few related questions, but I cannot get the answer to work for my situation. Maybe it's because it is the `memoir` documentclass, maybe it's the bibliography manager (`natbib` is embedded in the `achemso` package). In any case, my bibliography right now shows up as a `chapter*`. I would like it to be included in the `toc` as a `subsection` (not starred!).

I would still like it to retain `chapter*` formatting for in the document. I'm ok even if the solution is to shut off the automatic `toc` entry and add a manual entry in the `toc`

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/U0ocyo4lGsQ

[Bibliography as \section instead of \section*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158871/bibliography-as-section-instead-of-section)

Here is my MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter1.bib}
    @article{ref1,
        author={Name, F.L},
        journal={J. Am. Chem. Soc},
        pages={1134--1145},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[super=true,journal=jacsat,maxauthors=0]{achemso} %for proper citation formatting

% tried this but it didn't work
%\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{References}}
% also tried this
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
    \frontmatter
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} 
    \tableofcontents\clearpage
    \mainmatter
        \begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
            \setsecnumdepth{subsection}
            \maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
            \settocdepth{subsection}
            \chapter{Chapter 1}
            \section{C1S1}
            \subsection{C1-SubS1}
            \lipsum[1]\cite{ref1}
            \subsection{C1-SubS2}

            \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
            \bibliographystyle{achemso}
            \bibliography{chapter1}
        \end{filecontents}

    \include{chapter1}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This redefines `\@memb@bchap` and uses `subsection` instead of `chapter` for `\addcontentsline`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter1.bib}
    @article{ref1,
        author={Name, F.L},
        journal={J. Am. Chem. Soc},
        pages={1134--1145},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[super=true,journal=jacsat,maxauthors=0]{achemso} %for proper citation formatting


\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} 
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\mainmatter

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{C1S1}
\subsection{C1-SubS1}
\lipsum[1]\cite{ref1}
\subsection{C1-SubS2}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@memb@bchap}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}%
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\bibname}%
  \fi
  \prebibhook}
\makeatother
\bibliography{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both your answers worked just perfectly! I wish I could mark them both as the solution

Comment: Turns out in the larger document, only this one worked

Comment: @JM: Well, you should give touhami the chance to improve his post if you think there's something wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. We use this patch

```
\let\mtaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\mtchaptoc}{%
\def\addcontentsline##1##2##3{%
\mtaddcontentsline{##1}{subsection}{##3}
\let\addcontentsline\mtaddcontentsline}}
\pretocmd{\bibliography}{\mtchaptoc}{}{}
```

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter1.bib}
    @article{ref1,
        author={Name, F.L},
        journal={J. Am. Chem. Soc},
        pages={1134--1145},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[super=true,journal=jacsat,maxauthors=0]{achemso} %for proper citation formatting

% tried this but it didn't work
%\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{References}}
% also tried this
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section}{}{}

\let\mtaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\mtchaptoc}{%
\def\addcontentsline##1##2##3{%
\mtaddcontentsline{##1}{subsection}{##3}
\let\addcontentsline\mtaddcontentsline}}
\pretocmd{\bibliography}{\mtchaptoc}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\protect\OnehalfSpacing}
    \frontmatter
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} 
    \tableofcontents\clearpage
    \mainmatter
        \begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
            \setsecnumdepth{subsection}
            \maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
            \settocdepth{subsection}
            \chapter{Chapter 1}
            \section{C1S1}
            \subsection{C1-SubS1}
            \lipsum[1]\cite{ref1}
            \subsection{C1-SubS2}

            \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
            \bibliographystyle{achemso}
            \bibliography{chapter1}
        \end{filecontents}

    \include{chapter1}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the larger document, this ends up changing the formatting of subsequent chapter listings, everything becomes tabbed over to be at the subsection level, and I get an error as well  ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@chapapp@head 
                          \@cftbsnum 3\@cftasnum 
l.63 ... of Small-Molecule Systems}{66}{chapter.3}
                                                  
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@chapapp@head 
                          \@cftbsnum 4\@cftasnum 
l.84 ... Complex Organic Reactions}{98}{chapter.4}

Comment: @JM I will see.